# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle override profile form : field form empty?

Tags: symfony, overriding, profile, fosuserbundle

I overrided registration form from FOSUserBundle with additionals fields: it works well.

When I apply the same logic to override Profile Form : the form appears well with my additionals  fields but all is empty (the fields do not contain values ​​of the connected user).

Note: when I use the default form from the bundle the profile form contains the values ​​of the connected user.

Is there a specific action compared to override the registration form to retrieve the values ​​of the connected user ?

HERE IS CODE :

## src/Vn/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
 ...
  vn_user.profile.form.type:
    class: Vn\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
    arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: vn_user_profile }

  vn_user.form.handler.profile:
    class: Vn\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler
    arguments: ["@fos_user.profile.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager"]
    scope: request
    public: false
```

## symfony/app/config/config.yml

```
  fos_user:
  ...
  profile:
        form:
              type: vn_user_profile
              handler: vn_user.form.handler.profile
```

## src/Vn/UserBundle/Form/Type/ProfileFormType.php

```
  namespace Vn\UserBundle\Form\Type;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
  use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;

  class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
  {    
      public function buildUserForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
      {        
      parent::buildUserForm($builder, $options);

          // custom field       
          $builder->add('profile',new MyProfileFormType(),array(
                    'label' => 'PROFILE'
                    ));

      }

      public function getName()
      {
          return 'vn_user_profile';
      }
  }
```

## src/Vn/UserBundle/Form/Type/MyProfileFormType.php

```
namespace Vn\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class MyProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add('birthday','birthday', array(
        'input' => 'array',
        'widget' => 'choice',

        'label'  => 'Birthday',
        ))
        ->add('firstname','text', array(
        'trim' => true,
        'label'  => 'Firstname',
        ))
        ->add('lastname','text', array(
        'trim' => true,
        'label'  => 'Lastname',
        ))
        ->add('gender','choice', array(
        'choices'   => array('1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'),
        'expanded'  => true,
        'required'  => true,
        'label'  => 'Vous êtes',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'vn_user_myprofile';
    }


    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Vn\UserBundle\Document\Profile',

        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your questions in English http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Can you post the code from the controller where you use the form? This all looks fine, but none of it sets any data. It's just describing the forms structure. In your controller you must call `$form->setData($user);`

Answer (score 5):

I found the mistake in my file ProfilFormeHandler.php : in the function process() I called parent::onSucess() instead of parent::process() ... 
The result is a "silent" bug (silent because not fatal error appears) due to my fault of course

Thanks for time you spent to try to help me, very sorry !

```
  <?php
  // src/Vn/UserBundle/Form/Handler/RegistrationFormHandler.php

  namespace Vn\UserBundle\Form\Handler;

  use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler as BaseHandler;

  use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;


  class ProfileFormHandler extends BaseHandler
  {

      public function process(UserInterface $user)
      {
          //parent::onSuccess($user);
            parent::process($user); // sound better of course : )



      }

      protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user)
      {
          $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
      }
  }
```